# Etch-A-Sketch: Columns will resize, but rows won't. (CSS Grid)

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-grid

I am creating an Etch-A-Sketch project as part of The Odin Project's foundations course. I have created a 16x16 grid, and the amount of cells in the grid will change depending on the user's input to a prompt.

My problem is that the amount of cells in the columns will change, but not the amount of cells in the rows. This results in the etch-a-sketch pad being made up of rectangles rather than evenly placed squares.

For example: If the user enters "32", there will be 32 cells in each column. But still only 16 columns. I need the grid to be 32x32 instead of 32x16.

```
const container = document.querySelector("#container");
const buttonSize = document.querySelector("#gridsize");
const buttonRainbow = document.querySelector("#gridsize");
let cell = document.querySelectorAll('.cell');
let cellAmount = 16;
window.onload = createGrid(cellAmount);
cell.onmouseover = mouseOver();

// creates a 16x16 grid
function createGrid(e){
    for (let i = 0; i < e*e; i++){
        const div = document.createElement("div");
        div.classList.add("cell");
        container.appendChild(div);
    }
}

// changes cell colors to black on mouseover
function mouseOver(){
    let cell = document.querySelectorAll('.cell');
    cell.forEach((cell) => {
        cell.addEventListener('mouseover', function(){
            cell.style.background = "black";
        })
    })
}

// resizes the grid and resets sketch
buttonSize.addEventListener('click', () => {
    for (i = 0; i < cell.length; i++){
        cell[i].style.removeProperty("black")
    } 
        let userAmount = prompt("Select your pixel size (Default: 16)");
        if (userAmount == ""){
            userAmount == 16;
        }
        while (parseInt(userAmount) < 4 || parseInt(userAmount) > 100){
            userAmount = prompt("Sorry, please enter a number between 4 and 100.");
        }
        cellAmount = parseInt(userAmount);
        while (container.hasChildNodes()){
            container.removeChild(container.firstChild);
        }
        createGrid(cellAmount);
        mouseOver();
});
```

```
#container {
    margin-top: 25px;
    display: inline-grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(16, 1fr);
    grid-template-rows: auto;
    border: 7.5px solid black;
    border-radius: 10px;
    height: 575px;
    width: 575px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.cell {
   border: 1px solid black;
   box-sizing: border-box;
}

#title {
    display: flex;
    background-color: crimson;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 270px;
    height: 72px;
    margin-left: 815px;
    margin-top: 50px;
    border-style: solid aqua;
    border-radius: 35px;
    font-size: small;
}

#buttons {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    gap: 75px;
    margin-top: 40px;
}

#gridsize {
    background: black;
    color: white;
    border: none;
    width: 100px;
    height: 30px;
    font-size: large;
    border-radius: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

#rainbow {
    background: black;
    color: white;
    border: none;
    width: 100px;
    font-size: large;
    font-weight: bold;
    border-radius: 20px;
}

#tipmessage {
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 40px;
}

html {
    background-color: snow;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 
        <title>Etch-A-Sketch.</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    </head>

    <body>
     
        <div id="title">
            <h1>Etch-A-Sketch. &#128397</h1>
        </div>
        

        <div id="buttons">
            <button id="gridsize">Size</button>
            <button id="rainbow">Rainbow</button>
        </div>
        

        <div id="container"></div>

        <div id="tipmessage">
            <h3><em>'We don't make mistakes, just happy little accidents' - Bob Ross</em></h3>
        </div>

    </body>

    <script src="script.js" defer></script>

</html>
```

I have tried changing the CSS grid properties for `#container` however this has not solved the problem. I have inspected my JS but can't seem to figure out if the problem is coming from the JS, or the CSS.

For example, I tried changing my CSS Grid's columns and rows to "auto" but this completely ruined the grid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is coming from the CSS. This part:

```
#container{
    ...
    grid-template-columns: repeat(16, 1fr);
    ...
}
```

Because the grid-template-columns amount is hard-coded into the style-sheet it will not change with the new grid size received from the user. If the amount of columns is set to, say 33 and then you edit grid-template-columns via browser tools to match 33 then the divs created will appear as squares.

As it is written there *must* be 16 columns in the grid and no more or less.

So when you call the function that creates the grid you have to edit the  grid-template-columns attribute of #container so that the grid-template-columns of the container is updated along with the amount of cells in the grid.

```
function createGrid(e){
    container.style.gridTemplateColumns = `repeat(${e},1fr)`  // This will make the divs square
    for (let i = 0; i < e*e; i++){
        const div = document.createElement("div");
        div.classList.add("cell");
        container.appendChild(div);
    }

}
```